# How to Customize the message format for Python logging?

Tags: python-3.x, logging

Im in the process of setting up a logger for my programm

```
custom_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
custom_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s;%(message)s;%(filename)s;%(lineno)d',"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('beispiel.log')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
custom_logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

I want to logg this part `custom_logger.info(z1serial.isOpen())` 

it adds a TRUE to the log file 

`2020-03-03 13:47:38;True;test.py;55`

how can I insert a specific message like `device connected; True, so it apears in the log file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to insert a argument to the message it needs to be in format string like this

`custom_logger.debug('device connected: %s',z1serial.isOpen())`

nothing fancy